# Page stops processing after using createObject for a custom java class

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to incorporate some java classes within a ColdFusion application. I'm using the new functionality in ColdFusion 10 where I can specify within my Application.cfc where ColdFusion should look for .class files. When I try to create one of these objects using `createObject` the page seems to stop processing. I want to emphasis there is no error on the page, it's as if a `<cfabort>` was included instead.

My Application.cfc

```
<cfcomponent accessors="true" output="false" persistent="false">
    <cfscript>
    THIS.javaSettings = {LoadPaths = ["C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\JavaTest\Hybrid\java\bin"], loadColdFusionClassPath = true, watchInterval = 10, reloadOnChanges = true};
    </cfscript>
</cfcomponent>
```

My Java file

```
public class TestRT {
    public static String sayHello(){
        return "hello";
    }
    public static String echo(String e){
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

My cfm

```
<html>
<head><title>Hello World</title></head>
    <body>
        <h2>Echo example</h2>

        <cfset hello = createObject("java","TestRT").init()>
        <cfoutput>Hi #hello.echo("marc")#</cfoutput>

        <h2>End - I NEVER SHOW</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Project structure:

[image: My Project structure]

The output:

> [image: Code output]

My log files:

Although I get no error on the page, thanks to Leigh I have several errors in my log file:

### In exception.log:

```
"Error","http-bio-8500-exec-2","02/09/15","06:18:35",,"TestRT : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 The specific sequence of files included or processed is: C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\JavaTest\Hybrid\index.cfm, line: 8 "
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: TestRT : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

### In coldfusion-error.log:

```
Feb 09, 2015 6:18:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [CfmServlet] in context with path [/] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: TestRT : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

If I change to a made up class I get the expected error so it does find my class, it just doesn't like it. What is going wrong and how can I use my java class within ColdFusion?

Comment: Did you check all of the log files, including /runtime/logs? The above worked fine for me with CF10 (noticed your file path refers to CF11?) Though normally you would at least assign a "name" in the Application.cfc.  Side note, no need to invoke `init()` (ie the psuedo-constructor) when calling a static method.

Comment: @Leigh Interesting, I have found several errors/exceptions in my logs (see updated question), Re version 11: My personal copy of cold fusion is version 11 but at work we use 10 so I can only use features from 10.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. My java class has been compiled against java 8 but it seems the coldfusion JRE is java 7

Comment: @Leigh Will do, I want to make 100% sure it works when I get home but it seems pretty likely that'll be the issue

Comment: (Edit) Yep. Like any java project, you have to build for compatibility with whatever version the app will be running on, in this case java7.  Do not forget to write that up as an answer to close out the thread. RE: *at work we use 10* I would strongly recommend running the same version locally (you can also run both 10 and 11 side by side). Otherwise, you can never be certain how the code will behave until you upload it and the app breaks  (Yes, that is from personal experience ;-) .

Comment: If it turns out that the answer was java 7 vs. java 8 I would encourage the OP to post it as an answer to help others who might have this same problem.

Comment: @Leigh It was indeed the Java version that was the problem. Thanks for all your help

Comment: You are welcome (and thanks for posting the solution for next guy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was suggested by the message in exception.log [thanks to [Leigh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104223/leigh) for suggesting to look there], which can be found under cfusion\logs under your ColdFusion install directory, the problem was indeed that I was compiling my Java source under Java 8 but the JRE bundled within my version of ColdFusion only supported up to Java 7. By changing my "Compile Compliance level" to 1.7 (aka Java 7) I was able to get the above example to run perfectly.

To change the Java version compiled to in eclipse:

File>Properties>Java Compiler Change "Compile Compliance level" remembering than 1.N is more commonly refered to as Java version N

[image]